# Why won't this JAVA GUI process past the first entry?

Tags: java, user-interface

In class today we put together a basic GUI for calculating the distance between two points. Neither the instructor nor my classmates could figure out why this GUI won't process. The code given to us was a framework and we just edited the old code to develop this. I compared my work to that of two other students and theirs worked while mine didn't.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.lang.Math;
public class D2 extends JFrame
{
//****************************************
//** GUI Structure
//** Title: Holston Middle School
//** Weight prompt (jlabel, jtext)
//** planet pulldown
//** Weight on planet (jlabel, jtext)
//** calculate button
//****************************************
public JTextField entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4, output1;
public JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4, label5;
public JButton CalculateButton;
public String mtitle, cmessage;

public D2()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));

    label1 = new JLabel("x1");
    add(label1);
    entry1 = new JTextField(8);
    add(entry1);
    setEnabled(true);
    setVisible(true);

    label2 = new JLabel("x2");
    add(label2);
    entry2 = new JTextField(8);
    add(entry2);
    setEnabled(true);
    setVisible(true);

    label3 = new JLabel("y1");
    add(label3);
    entry3 = new JTextField(8);
    add(entry3);
    setEnabled(true);
    setVisible(true);

    label4 = new JLabel("y2");
    add(label4);
    entry4 = new JTextField(8);
    add(entry4);
    setEnabled(true);
    setVisible(true);

    label5 = new JLabel("Distance");
    add(label5);
    output1 = new JTextField(8);
    add(output1);
    setEnabled(false);
    setVisible(true);
    CalculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    add(CalculateButton);
    CalculateButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            String entry1string = entry1.getText();
            Double e1value = Double.valueOf(entry1string);
            String entry2string = entry2.getText();
            Double e2value = Double.valueOf(entry2string);
            String entry3string = entry3.getText();
            Double e3value = Double.valueOf(entry3string);
            String entry4string = entry4.getText();
            Double e4value = Double.valueOf(entry4string);
            String wmessage = "You selected ";
            String wtitle = "Pop Up Box";
            if (true) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, wmessage, wtitle, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            double distance = (Math.pow((e1value - e2value), 2) + Math.pow((e3value - e4value), 2));
            DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("####.##");
            String outstring = fmt.format(distance);
            output1.setText("");
            output1.setText(outstring);
        }//** actionPerformed
    }); //** Action Listener
    } //** D2 constructor

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        D2 frame = new D2();
        frame.setTitle("Distance Calculator");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 200);
        frame.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } //** main
} //** class
```

Inserting print statements and setting the value of label1 to another value results in no change in the GUI. Any help?

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During creation of `output1` you wrote `setEnabled(false);`. Possibly you meant that `output1` controll should be disabled. But instead of that you disabled the whole container, thus all elements are not editable\clickable. To fix the behaviour set this property directly to control:

```
output1 = new JTextField(8);
add(output1);
output1.setEnabled(false);
output1.setVisible(true);
```

Hope this will help.

P.S. It seems that you also need to improve calculation itself by adding `Math.sqrt` (if I understood your idea correctly):

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((e1value - e2value), 2) + Math.pow((e3value - e4value), 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mikita is right. You could also consider adding a `JPanel` in your `JFrame` or at least add all your components (JButtons, JTextfields etc) into the `ContentPane` of the `JFrame`.

See the [Using Top-Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) tutorial and this [FlowLayout sample](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/FlowLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/FlowLayoutDemo.java).

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));
label1 = new JLabel("x1");
getContentPane().add(label1);
entry1 = new JTextField(8);
getContentPane().add(entry1);
```

or

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));
label1 = new JLabel("x1");
panel.add(label1);
entry1 = new JTextField(8);
panel.add(entry1);
getContentPane().add(panel);
```